# Drawing a line segment using cocos2djs

Tags: javascript, canvas, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-js

I want to draw a line segment using cocos2d-js. Suppose I have two points

```
cc.p(50,50);
```

and

```
cc.p(200,200);
```

, how do I connect these two points using a line?

I've looked around and

```
cc.DrawNode();
```

is not having a drawLine() method though it has a drawDot() method. So I thought I should go for

```
cc.DrawingPrimitiveCanvas(renderContext);
```

but I can't seem to get it working. I am only starting to learn cocos2d-js. It would be very helpful if you can show me how to draw a simple line, be it using DrawNode() or DrawingPrimitiveCanvas().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
var line = new cc.DrawNode();
line.drawSegment(cc.p(50,50), cc.p(200,200),2);
```

I should've been looking for the 'drawSegment' method within 'DrawNode'.

Here's the usage:

```
drawSegment(from, to, lineWidth, color)
//draw a segment with a radius and color
```

Parameters:

```
{cc.Point} from, 
{cc.Point} to,
{Number} lineWidth,
{cc.Color} color
```